# Problem setting a single page public using Spring+Keycloak, root seems to override all permissions?

Tags: java, spring, security, keycloak, vaadin14

I am quite new to using Spring and the Spring security, so maybe the problem is small.

**Current set-up**:

We have made an application using Vaadin, Spring and Keycloak. Now to my understanding Spring security and Keycloak can work together to make pages accessible to logged in users or not. So far we have multiple pages that work just fine, as long as you are logged in.

**Goal**:

Now we want to add a public page "hardware", that requires no login. This seems to be harder than it should be? The hardware URL would be like /hardware/(valid serial number). The /hardware path itself does not exist and is never used as a path, only in combination with the serial number!

**Attempt**:

In our SecurityConfig we have the following code:

```
http.csrf()
              .disable()
              .logout()
              .logoutUrl("/logout")
              .permitAll(false)
              .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/UIDL/**").permitAll()
              .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/HEARTBEAT/**").permitAll()
              .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/hardware/**").permitAll()
              .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority(Privilege.AUTHENTICATED);
```

But now on our public page "hardware" we are still met with the "Server connection lost, trying to reconnect..." error of doom. Is it likely that somewhere either Spring or Vaadin or Keycloak are calling some other things that make this page fail, or is it that this configuration is wrong?

Or maybe any tips in general on how about to go debugging this? We have been trying to get past this for over a week now with absolutely zero progress....

Regards,

Arnoud

Answer (score 0):

Why you use the /** after hardware ?
It covers all the sub links of hardware and not itself

Comment: Ah good point, the page only works if there is a valid serial after the path, the path itself does not exist, only in combination with a valid serial number. :) I have updated the question to include this bit, good observation!